# Protractor sendKeys to Modal return element not visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I have an odd issue in protractor.

All I need to do is test form thats in a modal. I can confirm that the modal is open, but then I want to sendKeys to the input(s).

```
  element(by.id('modal')).click().then(function () {

    var modal = $('.modal');

    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(modal), 5000);

    expect(modal.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy(); 

    element(by.model('userInput.firstName')).sendKeys('HELLO'); // <- this fails

  })
```

This test will fail with ElementNotVisibleError. But when I set the modal to auto open once the page is hit (rather than via a button click), I make sure the modal is displayed and send the keys. This passes fine.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for the *visibility of the `input` element* instead:

```
var modal = $('.modal');
var modalInput = modal.element(by.model('userInput.firstName'));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(modalInput), 5000);
modalInput.sendKeys('HELLO');
```

Comment: Thanks. Why would I have to wait for the input to be visible when the modal has to be in view before the inputs?

Comment: @Ben question is: why not? Did it help? Thanks.